# Kendo Dropdown - want to display all but a specific firm on the dropdown

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I would like to display all but a specific firm on the dropdown. In my case it would be the name. At the moment, drop down displays all but first subscriber on the table but I would like to pass the name of the firm as a parameter and do not include the name in the drop down.

```
function ConfirmMigrate(e) {
     var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
     $("#window").data("kendoWindow").content(detailsTemplate(dataItem));
     // var name = dataItem.SubscriberFirmName;
     $('#Subscribers').kendoDropDownList();
     var dropDown = $("#Subscribers").data("kendoDropDownList");
     var itemToRemove = dropDown.dataSource.at(0);
     dropDown.dataSource.remove(itemToRemove);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple for loop will do exacly what you need:

```
var data = dropDown.dataSource.data();

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    var item = data[i];
    if(item.value == name){
        dropDown.dataSource.remove(item);
        break;
    }
}
```